# can't make a jfiddle example work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX programming, but I found an example on jfiddle that is very close to what I'm trying to accomplish. I can't make it work, however. I put a reference to the same version of jquery in the header, but the page doesn't do anything when I hit the submit button on 'my version'. Also, the animated loading cursor spins forever. Here is the jfiddle reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Here is what I *think* is the same version. I must be doing something wrong, but I'm really not sure what. I can't seem to make it work in StackOverflow either.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    
    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();
        
        $("#loadingimg").show();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function(returnhtml){                          
                $("#result").html(returnhtml); 
                $("#loadingimg").hide();                    
            }           
        });    
        
    });
    
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;       
}

form span{  
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}

label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;     
}

input[type="text"]{
    border: 1px soild #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"]{
     padding: 5px 15px;       
}

span#result{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ff9;        
}

img#loadingimg{
    display: none;                   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">
    
    <span id="result"><a href="http://wp.me/p2O9K2-b">jQuery + AJAX form submit script.</a></span>
   
    <span>        
        <label>Message: </label>
        <input type="text" name="html" placeholder="Howdy..." />
    </span>
    
    <span>
        <label><img id="loadingimg" src="http://dev.cloudcell.co.uk/bin/loading.gif"/>   </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />      
    </span>
    
</form>
```

Comment: Check for console errors in your browser..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO is sandboxed and will not allow the ajax to go through.

As for the original example, jsFiddle has a "fauxjax" kind of setup that will *simulate* ajax responses when you use `action="/echo/html/"` which is why the original example *appears* to work (though it is just simulated):

[image]

#### [See the Jsfiddle Docs for more info on this feature](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)

If you are trying to run this example on your own server etc, make sure to update the action attribute in `<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">` to point to the file, on your server or elsewhere, that will receive and respond to your ajax call  (like a php script)

Since you're new to Ajax, it may also be helpful to learn about [CORRS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request) which will apply if you are ever trying to send an ajax request from one domain and have it received and/or responded to from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work here because `http://stackoverflow.com` cannot make cross origin requests to `http://stacksnippets.net/echo/html/`

it probably doesn't work for you because you don't have `/echo/html` service in your backend